# Why does my page have an additional scroll to it?

Tags: html, css

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
  html,
  body {
    font-family: helvetica;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .chatContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .chatWindow {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 14px;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #EEE;
  }
  
  .messages {
    //margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .message {
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .yours {
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  
  .yours .message {
    margin-right: 25%;
    background-color: #EEE;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .yours .message.last:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -7px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #EEE;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  }
  
  .yours .message.last:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -10px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  .mine {
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
  
  .mine .message {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 25%;
    background: rgb(0, 120, 254);
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .mine .message.last:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -8px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: rgb(0, 120, 254);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  }
  
  .mine .message.last:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -10px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  .inputField {
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    font-family: helvetica;
    border: solid 1px #EEE;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  
  .attatchImage {
    background-image: url("https://kieferfoto.hu/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Flat-Camera-Icon.png");
    width: 5%;
    height: 5%;
  }
  
  .attatchImage:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 0.20s linear;
  }
</style>
<div class="chatContainer">
  <div class="chatWindow" id="chatWindow">
    <div class="chat">
      <div class="yours messages">
        <div class="message last">
          Hello, how's it going?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mine messages">
        <div class="message">
          Great thanks!lol
        </div>
        <div class="message last">
          How about you??trgrtgrgrgrtgrtgertgrtgrt
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="yours messages">
        <div class="message last">
          Hello, how's it going?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mine messages">
        <div class="message">
          Great thanks!lol
        </div>
        <div class="message last">
          How about you??trgrtgrgrgrtgrtgertgrtgrt
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="yours messages">
        <div class="message last">
          Hello, how's it going?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mine messages">
        <div class="message">
          Great thanks!lol
        </div>
        <div class="message last">
          How about you??trgrtgrgrgrtgrtgertgrtgrt
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="yours messages">
        <div class="message last">
          Hello, how's it going?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mine messages">
        <div class="message">
          Great thanks!lol
        </div>
        <div class="message last">
          How about you??trgrtgrgrgrtgrtgertgrtgrt
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="yours messages">
        <div class="message last">
          Hello, how's it going?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mine messages">
        <div class="message">
          Great thanks!lol
        </div>
        <div class="message last">
          How about you??trgrtgrgrgrtgrtgertgrtgrt
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="yours messages">
        <div class="message last">
          Hello, how's it going?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mine messages">
        <div class="message">
          Great thanks!lol
        </div>
        <div class="message last">
          How about you??trgrtgrgrgrtgrtgertgrtgrt
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="yours messages">
        <div class="message last">
          Hello, how's it going?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mine messages">
        <div class="message">
          Great thanks!lol
        </div>
        <div class="message last">
          How about you??trgrtgrgrgrtgrtgertgrtgrt
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="yours messages">
        <div class="message last">
          Hello, how's it going?
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="inputField" placeholder="Enter message">
</div>
```

This seems to give me a page that doesnt fit on the screen, I want it to fill the current screensize both width and height but it seems to fill the width but not the height; it goes beyond the screensize.
Here is a demo of this: www.fightmymonster.rf.gd/Chat

Any help? I can't find whats causing this, I've tried removing certain elements but it just ruins the rest and doesn't even solve my issue.

Comment: set     `html{
    overflow:hidden;
    }`

Comment: height:100% + padding + height of input --> scroll

Comment: This removes the 'y' overflow bar however, now I am unable to reach my input field. I would like everything to fit within the active screen size.

Comment: set `min-width:100%`

Comment: @TemaniAfif How would I fix this then please?

Comment: @jasinth premkumar In the html attribute?

Comment: yes in the html @BrandonS

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix it, It only ensures the width doesn't go below 100%. @jasinth premkumar

Comment: sorry i meant max-width